# Laravel 5.3 Scope chain not working as expected

Tags: laravel-5.3

I'm chaining two scopes. I expect that the model will return with only rows that answer the constraints in BOTH scopes.

```
public function scopeHasImages() {
    return $this->has('images');
}

public function scopeCompleted() {
    return $this->where('status', 'complete');
}
```

and then I use

```
Subject::completed()->hasImages()->limit(100)->get()[0]->status;
```

unfortunately result is "pending"

just to make things clear, this works:

```
Subject::completed()->limit(100)->get()[0]->status;
```

result is "complete"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **[Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes)** to return a `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instance:

```
public function scopeHasImages($query) 
{
    return $query->has('images');
}

public function scopeCompleted($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', 'complete');
}
```

And then chaining the scopes will work:

```
Subject::completed()->hasImages()->limit(100)->get();
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, so simple. Its exactly what the doc says too. Thanks.